# Is the "FOR-NEXT" loop wrong in this GW-BASIC program?

Tags: gw-basic

I got the original version of this program from a computer magazine. It asked for an Arabic number ranging from 1 to 3999 and converted it into the Roman equivalent. That worked flawlessly. Now I want to display the whole list of that range, so I've used a FOR-NEXT loop, but the program doesn't go farther than V. What is wrong with my loop?

```
1 REM *** ARABIC-ROMAN NUMBERS CONVERTER
2 REM *** From MegaOcio 25, p. 69
3 REM *** Last modification 11/10/23
6 REM ******************************************
8 SCREEN 0:WIDTH 80:KEY OFF:CLS
19 FOR FI=1 TO 3999
20 IF FI<4 THEN H=FI:REPE$="I":GOSUB 90:GOTO 100
25 IF FI=4 THEN TT$=TT$+"IV":GOTO 100
30 IF FI<9 THEN TT$=TT$+"V":FI=FI-5:GOTO 20
35 IF FI=9 THEN TT$=TT$+"IX":GOTO 100
40 IF FI<40 THEN H=INT(FI/10):REPE$="X":GOSUB 90:FI=FI-(H*10):GOTO 20
45 IF FI<50 THEN TT$=TT$+"XL":FI=FI-40:GOTO 20
50 IF FI<90 THEN TT$=TT$+"L":FI=FI-50:GOTO 20
55 IF FI<100 THEN TT$=TT$+"XC":FI=FI-90:GOTO 20
60 IF FI<500 THEN H=INT(FI/100):REPE$="C":GOSUB 90:FI=FI-INT(H*100):GOTO 20
65 IF FI<900 THEN TT$=TT$+"D":FI=FI-500:GOTO 20
70 IF FI<1000 THEN TT$=TT$+"CM":FI=FI-900:GOTO 20
75 IF FI=1000 THEN TT$=TT$+"M":GOTO 100
80 IF FI<4000 THEN H=INT(FI/1000):REPE$="M":GOSUB 50:FI=FI-INT(H*1000):GOTO 20
90 IF H=4 THEN TT$=TT$+"CD" ELSE TT$=TT$+STRING$(H,REPE$)
95 RETURN
100 PRINT FI;"- ";TT$;" ":TT$="":NEXT FI
110 K$=INPUT$(1):IF K$=CHR$(27) THEN PRINT:END ELSE RUN
```

Comment: Why do you pack entire subs (methods) on a single line? Rewrite that code to use one line per instruction, and your issue should be easier to debug.

Comment: Note that you have `GOSUB` inside your for (with a target _also_ within the for), so if one of these is called, the code flow gets really messy.

Comment: The original program just asked for an Arabic number and converted it into Roman. I've only added the FOR-NEXT, and both statements are there. Therefore the error message doesn't' make sense.

I'll to rewrite the program according to your instructions, but GW-BASIC doesn't make it easy. 

Thanks for taking a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

The question failed to mention that it doesn't stop at V but it is caught in an endless loop that goes up to 4 and then to 0(!) which shouldn't happen at all.  It happens because the code *in* the loop changes the value of the loop variable.  Look at all those `FI=FI-…` instances.  The code needs an independent loop variable that isn't altered within the loop.

Then it hangs at value 1001.  Comparing lines 40, 60, and 80 the `GOSUB 50` in line 80 should have been a `GOSUB 90`.  Then it runs from 1 to 3999.  Haven't checked the results though.

```
1 REM *** ARABIC-ROMAN NUMBERS CONVERTER
2 REM *** From MegaOcio 25, p. 69
3 REM *** Last modification 11/10/23
6 REM ******************************************
8 SCREEN 0:WIDTH 80:KEY OFF:CLS
19 FOR I=1 TO 3999:FI=I
20 IF FI<4 THEN H=FI:REPE$="I":GOSUB 90:GOTO 100
25 IF FI=4 THEN TT$=TT$+"IV":GOTO 100
30 IF FI<9 THEN TT$=TT$+"V":FI=FI-5:GOTO 20
35 IF FI=9 THEN TT$=TT$+"IX":GOTO 100
40 IF FI<40 THEN H=INT(FI/10):REPE$="X":GOSUB 90:FI=FI-(H*10):GOTO 20
45 IF FI<50 THEN TT$=TT$+"XL":FI=FI-40:GOTO 20
50 IF FI<90 THEN TT$=TT$+"L":FI=FI-50:GOTO 20
55 IF FI<100 THEN TT$=TT$+"XC":FI=FI-90:GOTO 20
60 IF FI<500 THEN H=INT(FI/100):REPE$="C":GOSUB 90:FI=FI-INT(H*100):GOTO 20
65 IF FI<900 THEN TT$=TT$+"D":FI=FI-500:GOTO 20
70 IF FI<1000 THEN TT$=TT$+"CM":FI=FI-900:GOTO 20
75 IF FI=1000 THEN TT$=TT$+"M":GOTO 100
80 IF FI<4000 THEN H=INT(FI/1000):REPE$="M":GOSUB 90:FI=FI-INT(H*1000):GOTO 20
90 IF H=4 THEN TT$=TT$+"CD" ELSE TT$=TT$+STRING$(H,REPE$)
95 RETURN
100 PRINT I;"- ";TT$;" ":TT$="":NEXT I
110 K$=INPUT$(1):IF K$=CHR$(27) THEN PRINT:END ELSE RUN
```

BTW: GW-BASIC has an integer division operator (`\`) and a modulo operator (`MOD`) which might make the code a bit simpler/clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, BlackJack! I've checked the results and it has worked flawlessly!I was going crazy trying with WHILE-WEND, FOR-NEXT loops and even with yet another cumbersome IF...GOTO (or GOSUB) structure. I guess I would have cracked it in the end, but the trial and error process was extremely time-consuming and frustrating, especially if there was a crucial typing mistake I hadn't spotted.
Thank you very much again! :-)